# Json Web Token issuer validation not working

Tags: java, jwt

I'm doing something very very basic with JWT - Im following the tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json-web-tokens-jjwt). I'm using the JWT library here https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

Code is:

```
    final Claims claims = new DefaultClaims()
            .setExpiration(new Date(LocalDateTime.now().plus(60, DAYS).toEpochSecond(UTC) * 1000));

    Map<String, String> extraInfo = ImmutableMap.of("admin", "true");
    claims.putAll(extraInfo);

    String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer("mycompany").setClaims(claims).signWith(HS512, secretKey).compact();

    Jwts.parser()
            .requireIssuer("mycompany")
            .require("admin", "true")
            .setSigningKey(secretKey)
            .parseClaimsJws(jwt);
```

Somehow, the `.requireIssuer("mycompany")` line leads to `MissingClaimException` error `Expected iss claim to be: mycompany, but was not present in the JWT claims.`

If I remove this check, the check for `admin: true` is fine. How could the issuer check possibly fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, don't use `DefaultClaims` directly in your code. It's from the `jjwt-impl` artifact which **should only be available in runtime**. Quoting the [documentation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt):

> JJWT guarantees semantic versioning compatibility for all of its artifacts except the `jjwt-impl.jar`. No such guarantee is made for the `jjwt-impl.jar` and internal changes in that `.jar` can happen at any time. Never add the `jjwt-impl.jar` to your project with `compile` scope - always declare it with `runtime` scope.

---

You could simply do the following with `Jwts.builder()`:

```
String jws = Jwts.builder()
        .setIssuer("mycompany")
        .setExpiration(Date.from(OffsetDateTime.now().plus(60, DAYS).toInstant()))
        .claim("admin", "true")
        .signWith(key)
        .compact();

Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = Jwts.parser()
        .requireIssuer("mycompany")
        .require("admin", "true")
        .setSigningKey(key)
        .parseClaimsJws(jws);
```

---

Alternatively to `DefaultClaims`, you can use a `Map<String, Object>` to store any extra claims you may have, as shown below:

```
Map<String, Object> claims = ImmutableMap.of("admin", "true");

String jws = Jwts.builder()
        .setIssuer("mycompany")
        .setExpiration(Date.from(OffsetDateTime.now().plus(60, DAYS).toInstant()))
        .addClaims(claims) // See the notes below
        .signWith(key)
        .compact();

Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = Jwts.parser()
        .requireIssuer("mycompany")
        .require("admin", "true")
        .setSigningKey(key)
        .parseClaimsJws(jws);
```

Bear in mind I am using `addClaims()` and not `setClaims()`:

- `addClaims()`: will *add* the given claims to the claims already present in the token.
- `setClaims()`: will *replace* the existing claims with the given ones.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the claims set by `setIssuer` with `setClaims`. You can fix it by setting issuer after setting claims.

```
String jwt = Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setIssuer("mycompany").signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey).compact();
```